# How to append SVG element to the existing SVG file - Node.js?

Tags: node.js, svg

I am having svg file as below which generates a simple rectangle

`simple.svg`

```
  <g id="seat">
       <rect x="130" y= "130" height="320" width="550" id="rect1" fill ="white" stroke="blue" ></rect>
  </g>
```

Now i want to append following svg element inside `rectangle(rect)`.

```
 <circle style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-miterlimit: 0.486;" cx="88" cy="84" r="5" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="0.486" stroke-width="0.35" id="A_8_05"/>
```

#### NOTE

`Technology/Programming` - Node.js

How can i achieve this?
Is there any `Svg parser` available in Node.js?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You do not need an SVG-parser. Any XML parser should do and there are plenty of them.

Comment: I tried using 'xml2js' parser.. How can i write or add using Xml2js parser?

Comment: This might be of help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML